# C++ Allocated pointers show unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dictionary

I am creating a grid of points in C++ and add them to a map, where the pointer to the point is the value and the ID of the point is key. However, the pointer seems to overwrite somewhere.

```
//At first, create them like an array
HPoint** points = new HPoint*[x_values.size() * y_values.size()];
//First x, then y
int y_count = y_values.size();
for(int x_index = 0; x_index < x_values.size(); x_index++) {
    for(int y_index = 0; y_index < y_values.size(); y_index++) {
        HPoint* newPoint = new HPoint();
        newPoint->setX(x_values[x_index]);
        newPoint->setY(y_values[y_index]);

        allPoints.insert(std::pair<int, HPoint*>(newPoint->getId(), newPoint));
        //This is the check within the loop
        refreshSegments();

        //Also insert into a grid, for better access
        points[x_index + y_count * y_index] = newPoint;

        //Assign connection
        if(y_index > 0) {
            HPoint* otherPoint = points[x_index + y_count * (y_index-1)];
            Segment* newSegment = new Segment(otherPoint, newPoint);
            allSegments.push_back(newSegment);
        }

        if(x_index > 0) {
            HPoint* otherPoint = points[x_index -1 + y_count * y_index];
            Segment* newSegment = new Segment(otherPoint, newPoint);
            allSegments.push_back(newSegment);
        }
    }
}
std::cout << "Out of the loop!: " << allPoints.size() << std::endl;

refreshSegments();
```

I use the refreshSegments() function to check, if there is some ID that is out of bounds:

```
void MeshGeneration::refreshSegments()
{
    //refresh points too
    for(std::map<int, HPoint*>::iterator it = allPoints.begin(); it!=allPoints.end();) {
        std::cout << it->second << " " << it->second->getId() << std::endl;

        if(it->second->getId() > it->second->getCounter() || it->second->getId() < 0) {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "Unexpected Id: " << it->second->getId() << " " << it->second;
            throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());

        }

        ++it;
    }
}
```

The map is actually an object member and looks like this:

```
std::map<int, HPoint*> allPoints;
```

The output looks like this. And it is clear, that the pointer 0xc61138 was fine when the check was called from within the loops, but was not fine when it was called from outside the loops.

```
0xc61138 0
0xc61188 1
0xc61240 2
0xc61348 3
0xc61438 4
0xc61500 5
0xc61620 6
0xc63030 7
0xc63118 8
0xc63200 9
0xc63388 10
0xc634e8 11
0xc63648 12
0xc63778 13
0xc63928 14
0xc63a60 15
0xc63b98 16
0xc63c60 17
0xc63d70 18
0xc63ea8 19
0xc63fe8 20
0xc64120 21
0xc63868 22
0xc64428 23
0xc64588 24
0xc64678 25
0xc64788 26
0xc648c0 27
0xc649f8 28
0xc64b30 29
0xc64c68 30
0xc64da0 31
0xc64f00 32
0xc64ff0 33
0xc65100 34
0xc65238 35
0xc65370 36
0xc654a8 37
0xc655e0 38
0xc64258 39
0xc65978 40
0xc65a68 41
0xc65b78 42
0xc65cb0 43
0xc65de8 44
0xc65f20 45
0xc66058 46
0xc66190 47
0xc662f0 48
0xc663e0 49
0xc664f0 50
0xc66628 51
0xc66760 52
0xc66898 53
0xc669d0 54
0xc66b08 55
Out of the loop!: 56
0xc61138 13003528
```

I am really confused because this actually sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, depending on the number of points I am creating.

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I added a cout into the destructor, so that I would see if somehow a HPoint was being destructed. That doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: What if you also display `it->first`?  That will indicate whether `getId()` worked in the first place, since it's used as the key.

Comment: I think I found a solution... It looks like my indexing is wrong. Instead of doing 

points[x_index + y_count * y_index] = newPoint;

I should do

points[x_index + x_count * y_index] = newPoint;

I'm sorry, I looked so hard at it before...

Comment: Thanks Paddy, I think I found the solution and am testing it now. I'm so sorry, I stared at my code forever but didn't see this...

Comment: Btw, @paddy, what you said wouldnt work because the key will be fine and doesn't access the object itself. So, the key is only an int number.

Comment: I was only suggesting that you have a more critical look at what you are doing, and try outputting values that you think are correct, but nevertheless might not be what you expected.  This is a pretty standard debugging technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your x and y sizes the same? If not, you can be in trouble having the index mapping broken, normally it is x + y * x_size, not y.